# aldryn-search for Django CMS to search full text

Tags: django, search, content-management-system, django-haystack

How this could be done?
For now I get only indexes that are addressed to the page titles. Like cms.title objects are indexed.

I have add the app like intended:

```
    #settings.py
    #TODO: It's not recommended for production use but it will return results.
    HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.simple_backend.SimpleEngine',
        },
    }
    HAYSTACK_ROUTERS = ['aldryn_search.router.LanguageRouter', ]
    ALDRYN_SEARCH_REGISTER_APPHOOK = True
```

Is there any trigger that I'm unaware of?